# Android - Conflicting providers/authorities

Tags: android

I'm trying to install Kik Messenger twice. I have two accounts and don't like to log out because I lose all of my conversation history. I'm currently using Titanium backup's profile feature, which is a very nice fix, but it's still a pain having to switch back and forth between profiles. I might be looking for "perfect" when perfect doesn't exist. I am completely new to modding apks and Android in general, all of my work on this so far has been "trial and error". Anyways, here's what I have:

I have the Google Play version of Kik installed on my phone. I have extracted that app and modified the package name successfully using apktool. However, when I try to install, I get an error saying something about duplicate provider authority. So I did some research and learned that I'm supposed to edit this part of the AndroidManifest. So I have played around with that a little bit and after I change the authorities, I am able to install the modded app. However, it crashes immediately.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem with the provider/authorities?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're hitting is that the app has registered certain classes to handle particular events. These need to be unique across all installed apps and point to existing classes in the app that will perform some activity with the supplied information.

You bypassed the safety check when installing by changing the defined handlers in the Manifest but that didn't really fix it as they still need to actually point to a valid, working class that can handle the requests/events.

You would need to decompile, rename the classes involved and all references made to them and recompile the whole app to really fix the problem. However, I'd assume that it would likely be against the license. If the code is open source then it wouldn't be too big a task to rename some classes & packages then build the app. If it's closed source then it is a harder task.

What you can do is either set up your device to use multiple accounts (the OS not the app) as each user has a separate data storage and preference location that should allow you to have two configurations. Or you can request that the developers include some sort of multiple account handling or easy account swap feature.